# Creating a list of squares of range(1, 7) backwards using loop

Tags: python-3.x

[Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icBOZ.png)

I wanted to create a new list named b which consists squares of numbers ranging (1,7) but in backward order I'm getting results 2 times instead of one. Also I don't want to solve using range (6 , 0 , -1).

I tried to run while loop from end to first position and expecting to append(add) results in list b but I got result 2 times, how can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please give your code as text, not as image.

Answer (score 0):

```html
a= list(range(1,7))
print(a)
i = len(a)-1
b=[]

while i >= 0:
    b.append(a[i]**2)
    i -= 1
print(b)
```

[Picture check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7I9x.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).